# Faster way of adding negative signed to unsigned

Tags: bit-manipulation, rust

Assuming I have `a: usize` and a negative `b:isize` how do I achieve the following semantics - **reduce a by absolute value of b** in fastest manner possible?

I already thought of `a - (b.abs() as usize)`, but I'm wondering if there is a faster way. Something with bit manipulation, perhaps?

Comment: Are you worried about potential underflows? Is it possible for `a` to exceed the maximum representable by `isize`?

Comment: Don't underflows happen if `a < |b|`? I'm aware of potential underflows and have a solution that should take care of it  - the result will be used to essentially split the range (the `a` is really either `range.start` or `range.end` depending on `b` sign). If I assert that `range.start< split <range.end` I should be safe from under/over -flows.

Comment: If you want something faster, then I'd hope that you have already run benchmarks and seen that this is too slow. You can then provide us the benchmarks so we know that any proposed solution is faster. Even looking at assembly listings doesn't tell the true story. It's always possible (albeit fairly unlikely) that the `sub` instruction has a massive pipeline stall, for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why do you assume this is slow?  If that code is put in a function and compiled, on x86-64 linux, it generates the following:

```
_ZN6simple20h0f921f89f1d823aeeaaE:
    mov rax, rsi
    neg rax
    cmovl rax, rsi
    sub rdi, rax
    mov rax, rdi
    ret
```

That's assuming it doesn't get inlined... which I had to work at for a few minutes to *prevent* the optimiser from doing in order to get the above.

That's not to say it definitely couldn't be done faster, but I'm unconvinced it could be done faster by *much*.

Comment: It looks like it's being compiled in debug mode, with minimal optimisations.  Try https://play.rust-lang.org/ and don't forget to click "Release".  I couldn't get that site to compile with optimisations *and* produce output.

Comment: I see. However I'm more interested in a more bit twiddling way to achieve it for a variable length unsigned int.

Comment: @DanielFath: Then I think you should actually ask that; the question as-asked seems unlikely to get you want you want.

Answer (score 2):

If `b` is guaranteed to be negative, then you can just do `a + b`.

In Rust, we must first cast one of the operands to the same type as the other one, then we must use `wrapping_add` instead of simply using operator `+` as debug builds panic on overflow (an overflow occurs when using `+` on `usize` because negative numbers become very large positive numbers after the cast).

```
fn main() {
    let a: usize = 5;
    let b: isize = -2;
    let c: usize = a.wrapping_add(b as usize);
    println!("{}", c); // prints 3
}
```

With optimizations, `wrapping_add` compiles to a single `add` instruction.